# PDO FETCH_INTO - only map existing properties

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I'd like to know if there's a fetch method in PHP that will only map existing properties in the class?

For example if my class looks like this:

```
class Company {
    public $id;
}
```

And my query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM companies
...
```

Then the returned object should only contain `$id`, and nothing else.

That is I want the class to control the columns, not the query.

Comment: Then why not `SELECT id FROM companies ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using the magic method __set() with an empty body. All non-existing properties will never be created.

```
function __set($property, $value) {

}
```